# Is there a limit to the users in a Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if there's a limit to the Users created (E-Mail users), in a firebase database.

Please let me know if there is one and/or what it's at.

All the best.

I've already tried making a ton of user accounts, but I haven't yet hit any limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits), there is no limit to the number of registered users per project, and a limit of 100 million anonymous users per project.